# How to map errors in transpiled babel files back to source?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm working with an express app and am using babel to transpile my code to be able to use some ES6/7/8 goodies.

THe command I'm running to transpile the files is: `npx babel server --out-dir lib --watch`. Then to start my server, I run `nodemon lib/server.js`.

The issue I'm currently running into is that all errors are happening from the transpiled files in `/lib`, so the trace doesn't quite match with what is actually in the source, making it hard to debug.

So let's say an exception is thrown on line 10 in a transpiled file in `/lib`, that error doesn't match up to where the error actually is in the source since the trace is with respect to the transpiled file.

Is there a way I can get it to map correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Brian i suggest you to use "babel-polyfill" and "babel-register" modules.
add these modules in your main entry file for example refer the below code.
in this way you do not need to transpile your code seprately and can debug in the same ES6+ original code.

just add the start command simply as shown in the below code snippet, it will run your node.js code and transpiles all your ES6+ features as well at run time on fly.

Example:
   **app.js**

```
 // Added for regenerator runtime!!
  require('babel-polyfill');
// Transpile on the fly
  require('babel-register')({
   ignore: false,
   only: /\/src/,
  });
 require('dotenv/config');
 let server = require('./server');

 server.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, () => {
   console.info(`application started on port ${process.env.APP_PORT}`);
 });
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/app.js",
```

Happy Coding :)